# How to remove array item property using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

Here is my AngularJs Code

```
vm.selectedReviewer = [];
        // selected on a given reviewer by name
         function reviewerSelect(reviewer) {
            var idx = vm.selectedReviewer.indexOf(reviewer);
            // is currently selected
            if (idx > -1) {
                vm.selectedReviewer.splice(idx, 1);
            }
            // is newly selected
            else {              
                vm.selectedReviewer.push(reviewer);
            }
         }
```

Html code

```
<div>
                        <h3>With a simple array as input data</h3>                         
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">                                   
                                <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="reviewer in vm.reviewerList">
                                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedFruits[]" value="{{reviewer}}" ng-checked="vm.selectedReviewer.indexOf(reviewer) > -1" ng-click="vm.reviewerSelect(reviewer)"> {{reviewer.Name}}                                       
                                        <input type="text" name="TotalReviewMargin" ng-model="reviewer.ReviewCollectMargin">
                                        <input type="text" name="TotalReviewMargin" ng-model="reviewer.PerReviewCost">
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>                           
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <h4>selected Reviewer</h4>
                                <pre>{{vm.selectedReviewer|json}}</pre>
                            </div>                               
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Here is my [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uyryx.png)

All are working well but I want remove some item property from selected item.
When the checkbox is checked my expected output [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLyij.png).
When the item push on array this time some property not pushing in array.  How to do this?

Comment: The code works fine, check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/6o3senub/)

Comment: When I click checkbox ng-click="vm.reviewerSelect(reviewer)"  reviewer contains  {
    "Name": "Saif",
    "ReviewerId": 3,
    "WorkingBookCount": 0,
    "TotalReviewMargin": 0,
    "TotalReviewCollect": 0,
    "ReviewCollectMargin": "45",
    "PerReviewCost": "100"
  }  I want to remove this item some property like as WorkingBookCount,ReviewCollectMargin remove from this item. How to achieve this?

Comment: what is the expected output when the checkbox is checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From What I understood, you needed to delete some property of an object. Take [a look at this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t5mn73ep/1/).

You can create a deep copy of object so that it doesn't affect the `reviewerList` using:

```
  var tempObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(reviewer));
  delete tempObj.TotalReviewMargin;
  this.selectedReviewer.push(tempObj);
```

So, although you have

```
this.reviewerList = [
  {name: "test", ReviewCollectMargin: 10, PerReviewCost: 12,TotalReviewMargin : 0},
  {name: "test2", ReviewCollectMargin: 10, PerReviewCost: 12 ,TotalReviewMargin : 0},
  {name: "test3", ReviewCollectMargin: 10, PerReviewCost: 12,TotalReviewMargin : 0}
];
```

On checkbox click, you get:

```
[
 {
  "name": "test",
  "ReviewCollectMargin": 10,
  "PerReviewCost": 12
 }
]
```

*Note the `TotalReviewMargin` property is missing in selected value*